# Relative Layout gets messed up in different emulators

Tags: android, layout

**So I was designing my main page for my first app, and when I emulated it I noticed that the size of my stopwatch got a little bigger for some reason. So I took my phone and tested it on there and the results aren't pretty. I used dp which I was almost certain is % and not set value so I have no clue why it changes like that.**

Here is the images so it dosn't clutter my question https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hIUh.jpg

**menu1_layout.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="500dp"
            android:layout_height="800dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:background="@drawable/background3" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stopWatch"
        android:layout_width="225dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@drawable/stopwatch2"
        android:layout_marginTop="83dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom">

    <Chronometer
        android:id="@+id/aChronometer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginBottom="144dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:text="@string/Explanation"
            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:layout_above="@+id/button"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="26dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:text="= 0"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="-10dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/cookie"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_marginRight="-10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_marginBottom="84dp" />


    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Extra comment I ended up changing everything that was unnecessarily a button to imageview but the stopwatch has to be a button which is where idk how to fix it. **edit** I am seeing weights and other methods, but I have   no clue how to implement. Is there a way to just create set size for certain objects so when the background widens so do my images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run you particular layout in 5 different devices with different sizes, you will get 5 different results.

Well, this is because you have put specific values for `layout_height`, `layout_width` and the `margins`, like `225dp`, `200dp`. I know these are `independent pixels`, but when drawable is considered never set both `width` and `height` to a specific value. It messes up the aspect ratio. These settings will work well for one particular configuration of device, but not the rest. The device will pick different drawable based on the resolution of the device.

You need to try to design your relative to other views. Always make sure that the `layout_width` and `layout_hight` are in `wrap_content`. This will ensure that the `drawable` is loaded in correct aspect ration in all the devices and emulators.

Comment: Oh ok thank you, what I am planning on doing is editing the background and other objects so they won't mess up no matter where it is. I am going to try and use alignParent instead of touching margins/width. So I photoshopped the images to make it easier for me.

Comment: Ok I solved it. I put relative layouts within linear and almost cried, but I finally figured out how it works using weight, weight sum, gravity and trial and error.